# How to create GoogleMap Marker Listeners to open a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-markers

I am working on an app in which there are restaurants on a map (Google Map API) and in a list composant aside.

I have set a listener which opens the component AddRestaurant with a click on the map.
What I don't manage to do is to setting a listener to open the component ReadComments when the user clicks on a marker.
The click doesn't work, whether I put the listener in the component GoogleMap (create the map), or GoogleMarkers (create the markers), or MainMap (which imports the two others).

I'm sorry I can't put the code in a jsfiddle, so here are the code of the three map componants:

GoogleMap:

```
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="google-map" v-bind:id="mapName" ref="mainMap">
    </div>
<!--    Tuto ici : https://itnext.io/new-unnamed-post-8da9cdbf5df3-->
    <template v-if="Boolean(this.google) && Boolean(this.map)">
      <slot :google="google" :map="map"></slot>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  // Utilisation du plugin pour charger de manière asynchrone l'API
  const GoogleMapsAPILoader = require('google-maps-api-loader');

  export default {
    name: 'google-map',
    props: [
      'name',
      'defaultCenter'
    ],
    data: function() {
      return {
        google: null,
        mapName: this.name + "-map",
        userCoord: {},
        markers: [],
        map: null,
        bounds: null,
        infoWindow: null,
        position: {
          lat: null,
          lng: null
        }
      }
    },

    async mounted() {
      const google = await GoogleMapsAPILoader({
        apiKey: 'APIKEY'
      })
      this.google = google
      this.initMap();
      this.addChangeBoundsListener();
      this.openAddRestaurant();
    },
    methods: {
      // Initialise la carte
      initMap() {
        // Pour y faire référence plus facilement
        const element = this.$refs.mainMap
        const options = {
          center: this.defaultCenter,
          zoom: 12,
        }
        this.map = new this.google.maps.Map(element, options);
        this.infoWindow = new this.google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Emet google et map à MainMap
        this.$emit('map-initialized', {
          google: this.google,
          map: this.map
        })
      },
      addChangeBoundsListener() {
        // Pour utiliser les bounds pour l'affichage des restaurants dans la liste
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'bounds_changed', (event) => {
          this.$emit('map-bounds-changed')
        })
      },
      openAddRestaurant() {
        // Emet l'event pour ajouter un restaurant au click sur la carte
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', (event) => {
          this.$emit('map-clicked', event);
        })
      },
    }
  };
</script>

<style scoped>
  @media screen and (min-width: 446px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .main {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
  }

  .google-map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #26A65B;
    border-radius: 2rem;
  }
</style>
```

GoogleMarkers:

```
<template>
  <div class="google-markers">

  </div>
</template>


<script>
  export default {
    name: 'google-markers',
    props: {
      google: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      },
      map: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      },
      marker: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        mapMarker: null
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.mapMarker = new this.google.maps.Marker({
        position: this.marker.position,
        map: this.map,
        marker: this.marker,
        icon: this.getIconUrl(this.marker.type)
      })
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
      this.mapMarker.setMap(null)
    },
    afterDestroy() {
      this.refreshIcon;
    },
    methods: {
      // Dessiner les markers
      getIconUrl(markerType) {
        let icon
        switch (this.marker.type) {
          case 'restaurant':
            icon = 'https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/restaurant-table.png';
            break;
          case 'user':
            icon = 'https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/marker.png';
            break;
          default:
            icon = 'https://img.icons8.com/ultraviolet/48/000000/record.png';
            break;
        }
        return icon
      },
      // Ajout Event Listener sur les markers
      openReadComments() {
        // google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', (event) => {
        //   console.log('I am clicked');
        // });

        this.marker.addListener('click', function () {
          console.log('clicked');
        });
      },
    },
    computed: {
      refreshIcon() {
        this.mapMarker = new this.google.maps.Marker({
        position: this.marker.position,
        map: this.map,
        marker: this.marker,
        icon: this.getIconUrl(this.marker.type)
      })
      }
    }
  }
</script>


<style scoped>

</style>
```

MainMap:

```
<template>
  <google-map
    :center="customCenter"
    :defaultCenter="defaultCenter"
    @map-initialized="initialize"
    @map-bounds-changed="selectVisibleMarker"
    @map-clicked="openAddRestaurant"
  >
    <template slot-scope="{ google, map }">
      <google-markers v-for="marker in markers" :marker="marker" :map="map" :google="google"></google-markers>
      <google-markers v-if="userMarker !== {}" :marker="userMarker" :map="map" :google="google"></google-markers>
    </template>
  </google-map>
</template>

<script>
  import GoogleMap from './GoogleMap'
  import GoogleMarkers from './GoogleMarkers'

  export default {
    components: {
      GoogleMap,
      GoogleMarkers
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        google: null,
        mapName: this.name + "-map",
        userCoord: {},
        userMarker: {
          type: 'user'
        },
        marker: null,
        map: null,
        bounds: null,
        infoWindow: null,
        position: {
          lat: null,
          lng: null
        },
        defaultCenter: {
          lat: 48.842702,
          lng: 2.328434
        },
        customCenter: {
          lat: null,
          lng: null
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      // Vient de GoogleMap
      initialize(data) {
        this.map = data.map
        this.google = data.google

        this.askGeolocation()
      },
      // Demande si l'utilisateur accepte la géolocalisation, et recentre la carte sur sa position si acceptée.
      askGeolocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            const pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            this.customCenter = pos
            this.userCoord = pos
            this.userMarker = {
              ...this.userMarker,
              position: pos,
            }
            this.map.setCenter(this.customCenter)
            this.setPlaces(pos);

          }, () => {
            this.handleLocationError(true, this.defaultCenter);
          });
        } else {
          this.handleLocationError(false, this.defaultCenter);
        }
      },
      handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, pos) {
        console.log(pos)
        this.map.setCenter(pos)
      },
      // selectVisibleRestaurant dépend du tri et de la zone d'affichage de la carte, et est utilisé par Map et List
      selectVisibleMarker() {
        this.$store.commit('setBoundsValue', this.map.getBounds())
        this.$store.commit('selectVisibleRestaurant')
      },
      // ouvre le composant AddRestaurant avec lat et lng en query
      openAddRestaurant(event) {
        this.$router.push({ path: '/add-restaurant/', query: { lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng: event.latLng.lng() }});
      },
      // Ajout Event Listener sur les markers
      openReadComments() {
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.userMarker, 'click', (event) => {
          console.log('I am clicked');
        });

        // this.marker.addListener('click', function () {
        //   console.log('clicked');
        // });
      },
      // Google Places
      setPlaces(location) {
        this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        const service = new google.maps.places.PlacesServices(this.map);
        service.nearbySearch({
          location: location,
          radius: 500,
          type: ['restaurant']
        }, callback);
      }
    },
    computed: {
      // Génère les markers
      markers() {
        const markersArray = [
          ...this.$store.getters.getRestaurantList.map((restaurant, index) => {
            return {
              id: index,
              position: {
                lat: parseFloat(restaurant.lat),
                lng: parseFloat(restaurant.long),
              },
              type: 'restaurant'
            }
          })
        ]
        if (this.userMarker !== {}) {
          markersArray.push(this.userMarker)
        }
        return markersArray
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

For know I am stuck here (but have already tried to put this listener in GoogleMap and MainMap.
This is the method I tried to set in GoogleMarkers.

```
openReadComments() {
        // google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', (event) => {
        //   console.log('I am clicked');
        // });

        this.marker.addListener('click', function () {
          console.log('clicked');
        });
      },
```

I have tried to set a listener on the user marker (since there is only one, so no array problem) but it still doesn't work at all.
The listener doesn't work and there is no message in the console.

If someone does know to create such listeners (without the plugin available for Vuejs), it would be a great help. Thanks.